# WebScraping javascript page in python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, beautifulsoup, request

**Hello World,**

New in Python, I am trying to webscrape a javascript page : https://search.gleif.org/#/search/

Please find below the result from my code (using request)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" name="viewport"/>
<title>LEI Search 2.0</title>
<link href="/static/icons/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon"/>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:200,300,400,600,700,900&amp;subset=cyrillic,cyrillic-ext,greek,greek-ext,latin-ext,vietnamese" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/static/css/main.045139db483277222eb714c1ff8c54f2.css" rel="stylesheet"/></head>
<body>
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="/static/js/manifest.2ae2e69a05c33dfc65f8.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/static/js/vendor.6bd9028998d5ca3bb72f.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/static/js/main.5da23c5198041f0ec5af.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**The question:**
Instead of retrieving the above script: 
    "src="/static/js/manifest.2ae2e69a05c33dfc65f8.js" type="text/javascript""

### **I would like to have the content of the table in order to store it.**

**Table that I want to scrape**
[image]

Comment: What exactly do you want to find?

Comment: So the question is how to set proxy auth in selenium? You can google that and find some workarounds for selenium's limitations.

Comment: @pguardiario the question is how do I get the table content instead of the js.script.if you have any hint?

Comment: @SuperStormer, I want to scrape the table but instead of that Im getting the script js. Have you any idea on how to deal with it?

Comment: You would use selenium for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code is written using [PySelenium](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/).

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

country = []
legal_name = []
lei = []

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

for i in range(1,30395):
    driver.get('https://search.gleif.org/#/search/fulltextFilterId=LEIREC_FULLTEXT&currentPage='+str(i)+'&perPage=50&expertMode=false#results-section')

    time.sleep(5)

    country += [i.get_attribute('innerHTML') for i in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="table-cell country"]/a')]
    legal_name += [i.get_attribute('innerHTML') for i in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="table-cell legal-name"]/a')]
    lei += [i.get_attribute('innerHTML') for i in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="table-cell lei"]/a')]
```

#### Logging in (Change this with the respective elements.)

```
driver.find_element_by_id("UserName").send_keys("xxxx")
driver.find_element_by_name("Password").send_keys("yyyy")
driver.find_element_by_class("loginButton").click()
```

#### Get page content

`print(driver.page_source)`

Comment: THANK YOU very much it works :) Just have 2 more questions: how can I set my username and password (firefox is asking me authentification each time). Furthermore, how can I just display the content of the result (like request.content?)

Comment: @Annis15 Edited the answer to include your 2 questions.

Comment: Thanks again for the content page. However, when I try to add your codes find_element_by_id, nothing happen (with my username and pwd) . I have tried to change the "UserName" by "Username:" (how firefox popup display it) but nothing. However, the first question is solved, right now it's just trying to optimize the script.

Comment: @Annis15 Could you please provide the page URL your'e trying to scrape, so I can provide you the exact code for the login.

Comment: The page is the same that you scraped: driver.get('https://search.gleif.org/#/search/fulltextFilterId=LEIREC_FULLTEXT&simpleFilters%255Bentity.addresses.country%255D=DE&currentPage='+str(i)+'&perPage=50&expertMode=false#results-section')

Comment: I was thinking that it might be because of proxy ?